# Ruby on Rails - different jQuery results in development and production for adblock message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, adblock

In my application I added some jQuery codes to show a message when user has **adblock** on. In my **development ENV** I can see the message, but with same code in **production ENV** it doesn't work/do the same thing.

*Here is my code*

```
var canRunAds = true;
  function hallo(){
    $("#showmsg").html("<p>You are using adblock</p>");
  }
  if( window.canRunAds === undefined ){
    hallo();
  }
```

I even created a file called `showads.js` and included it to my `head` with `var canRunAds = true;` but in **production** it changes to `var canRunAds != 0;` for reasons.

How can I get it to work or is it something I do wrong?

Comment: `in production it changes to var canRunAds != 0;` How that??? Isn't it just some cache issue?

Comment: Yeah, it does. I cleared all cache as well and used another browser too. but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work.
Changed `showads.js` to `ads.js` and added code blow to footer.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if( window.canRunAds === undefined ){
        $("#showmsg").html("<p>You are using adblock</p>");
    }
  });
```

It looked like **adblock** didn't block `showads.js` but `ads.js`